# Getting value from input and compare the value with list value and update in display some comments?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**PROBLEM**:
I want to collect user input and transform those collected data into JavaScript and use it for the purpose of comparing those data with my already created list where data about my friend list is available which will enable to show my real friend as output. What's going wrong in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"></link>
    <title>Friendship Army</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-1">FRIENDSHIP SHOW</h1>
    <h2 class="text-2">FINDING REAL FRIENDS OF SHIVAKUMAR</h2>
    <form id="align-middle">
        <input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="Enter your friend name">
        <button id="submit" onclick="goat()">SUBMIT</button>
        <h3 class="text-3"></h3>
    </form>
    <script>
        const a=["RAJKUMAR","PREMKUMAR","VINOTHKUMAR"];
        const b=document.getElementById("text-input");
        const c=document.querySelector("submit");
        const d=document.getElementsByClassName("text-3");
        c.addEventListener("click",()=>
        {
            for (let i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                if(document.getElementById("text-input").value==a[i])
                {
                    d.innerHTML="100% SHIVAKUMAR FRIEND";
                }
                else
                {
                    d.innerHTML="YOU'RE NOT IN THE LIST...";
                }
            }
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no code, add in question

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues with your js code

1. The button ID was incorrect
2. The code was comparing the user input with a[i] instead of b.value
3. The text was not being updated properly
4. The function was being called every time, instead of only when the form was submitted.

```js
       const a = ["RAJKUMAR", "PREMKUMAR", "VINOTHKUMAR"];
        const b = document.getElementById("text-input");
        const c = document.getElementById("submit");
        const d = document.getElementsByClassName("text-3");

        c.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (b.value == a[i]) {
                    d[0].innerHTML = "100% SHIVAKUMAR FRIEND";
                    break;
                } else {
                    d[0].innerHTML = "YOU'RE NOT IN THE LIST...";
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
    <h1 class="text-1">FRIENDSHIP SHOW</h1>
    <h2 class="text-2">FINDING REAL FRIENDS OF SHIVAKUMAR</h2>
    <form id="align-middle">
        <input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="Enter your friend name">
        <button id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        <h3 class="text-3"></h3>
    </form>
```